# Take Me Down To The Homonym City

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

> A drop of water, or a deadline;
>
> Us without me, or lady-like sheep;
>
> Screw, or a disconsent;
>
> To have clothing, or a question of place;
>
> In a mirror what you see, or how you see;
>
> Not pre-recorded, or not dead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Each line of the poem describes

> Two homonyms

Going through line by line we see the following:

---

A drop of water, or a deadline;

> Dew/due

Us without me, or lady-like sheep;

> You/ewe

Sex, or a disconsent;

> Know/no

To have clothing, or a question of place;

> Wear/where

In a mirror what you see, or how you see;

> I/eye

Not pre-recorded, or not dead.

> Live/live

---

Taken altogether it sounds like

> Do you know where I live?

Based on the title I'm guessing

> Paradise City

Or maybe given the theme of this puzzle

> Pair O' Dice City

Comment: No problem! Anything to keep my mind off of finals.

Comment: How does the third one work again? I know (..huehue) that the verb "know" has another, more biblical sense, but its meaning is drastically different from "to tell male and female animals apart". Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: @Bass I think your confusion is because of improper wording by the questioner. The line probably should have been "To have sex with, or a disconsent" or something along those lines.

Comment: @noneuclideanisms My original intent was to have the answer to the final question be my actual city, which is the first letter of every line. I found your answer to be better, though. Either way, I don’t completely agree with this being “improper wording” on my part. Your version is actually the opposite of what I aim toward. Clarity and obviousness are great for most practical things, but it is not what I look for in a puzzle.

Comment: @kedarguru Although I agree that clarity and obviousness shouldn't be that important in puzzles, I believe it's important to maintain some degree of fairness in puzzles. In your case, you clued "sex" for "know" even though "sex" does not mean "to have sex with". Perhaps "Screw, or a disconsent" would have been better, although it uses slang.

Comment: @noneuclideanisms “screw” is a better word, so I’ve modified the puzzle accordingly. Thanks

Comment: @kedarguru Happy to help!